# not able to bind using ldap_bind through PHP

Tags: php, ldap

I am able to connect to LDAP through unix but when I try to do the same through PHP am not able to. Below is the code,

```
$server ='server';
$port = 3060;
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($server, $port) or die("Could not connect " .
$server . ":" . $port . ".");
$user = "cn=orcladmin";
$password ='password';
$ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn,$user,$password) ;
if(!$ldapbind)
{
  echo ldap_error($ldapconn);  #I get error invalid credentials
}
```

I am able to connect and also bind anonymously but in that case ldap_search does not work which is my final requirement. using the same credentials i.e cn=orcladmin and 'password' I am able to connect to ODSM. 
Also Ihave tested the connection using below on unix,

```
ldapbind -h 'server' -p 3060 -D "cn=orcladmin" -w 'password'
```

it gives below message:

```
bind successful
```

Is user specified differently while connecting through PHP?
Could someone please help?

Comment: Could you provide us with more informations? The full php code, what is the directory you want to connect to (AD, OpenLDAP, etc.), the LDAP directory log, etc.

Comment: $server ='servername;
$port = 3060;$user = "cn=orcladmin";$password='password';
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($server, $port) or die("Could not connect " . $server . ":" . $port . ".");
 if ($ldapconn){
        echo "able to connect"; <I get this message>$ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn,$user,$password) or die("cound not bind"); <I get could not bind>
  } trying to connect to OpenLDAP

Comment: You should edit your question with these informations, also try to use the formatting to render code in a more friendly way to read. Can you also tell us what is the Directory on which you try to bind?

Comment: Can try to do your `ldapbind` command with the `-x` option and tell us the result? : `ldapbind -h 'server' -p 3060 -D "cn=orcladmin" -w 'password' -x`

Comment: `ldapbind -h 'server' -p 3060 -D "cn=orcladmin" -w 'password' -X "dn:dc=us,dc=oracle,dc=com" '  gives bind successful but only when I set export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/IDMTOP/products/dir/oid and export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH. Does ORACLE_HOME has to do anything here?

Comment: Yes it has everything to do. When you set your `PATH` you're pointing the `ldapbind` binary to use in your command line to the ORACLE version of the ldapbind which seems to allow you to use the predefined `cn=orcladmin` user. But as far as the `LDAP` protocol, you should not be able to connect with a user which does not have a DN located inside the `rootDN`. (Exception is made if your directory internally manages the conversion, as AD does it with "login" like `samAccountName@domain`)

Comment: hi Esteban, I now need to use ldap_bind to connect to openLdap through php , how do I set oracle_home in php? so that I don't get invalid credentials error.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was with ORACLE_HOME, not sure how to set it in PHP but I wrote a shell script where ORACLE_HOME was set and able to successfully run ldapbind and ldapsearch.